# Application throwing my local path as an error on client's machine

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop

I am new to C#. Created a C# application which reads from a file and does some processing. I have manually put the files under `myProject/bin/Debug/files/`  (Note: manually copy-pasted file, not sure if i need to import in any way through the application - using SharpDevelop IDE). My code reads the file through

```
string query = File.ReadAllText(@"files\myfile.txt");
```

After I built and passed it to a client and it's working fine when they click on `myproject.exe`, it can locate the file. But when they trigger it using windows task scheduler, the error they get is:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Windows\system\files\myfile.txt'... at extractor.Program.query() in d:\workspace\test\Program.cs:line 81 (this is my local path, shoud show client's folder path instead)

Need help with:

1. How should i make the exe pick client's path, not my local?
2. Is that the right way to add files. Note that I kept it that way because I   want to give client the flexibility to change `myfile.txt` as necessary, without touching the **.exe** (without the need to build again)
3. Is this the right way to locate a file (`@"files\myfile.txt"`).

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like this

```
string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
String query = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(path, "files\\Test.txt"));
```

Comment: Better use [`Path.Combine(path, "files\\Test.txt")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt) instead of the string concatenation.

Comment: As i meantioned, I have added myfile.txt manually under the files folder. I haven't gone through the ide and add item or something. ".Assembly" is not for the files that u add through the ide?

Comment: let me give it a try. get back :)

Answer (score 6):

There are two different paths at play in your error message.

**Wrong Local Path**

The first is the path where the application tries to find the file. This, in your error is

> C:\Windows\system\files\myfile.txt

This path is searched because `File.ReadAllText`, when given a relative path name, will search under the Current Directory, which isn't necessarily the one where your app is installed - it can be changed by calls to [`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx), 3rd-party components or even using the Open File Dialog.

What you need to do is not use a relative path, but specify explicitly where your files are. You can do that by taking your currently executing EXE's path and appending `files\myfiles.txt` to it.
You can get the current EXE path using `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`.

**Developer path**

Your error message seems to point to a path on your developer machine, but this isn't actually where .NET is looking for hte file, but rather *the location of the original C# file where the exception was thrown*. This is because you included the PDB files which contain extra debug information - this debug information contains the dev workspace path, so you can find the error in your code.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. so, the right practice, i should delete the pdb file before passing others?

Comment: or it can just be sitting there, won't affect anything at the cilent's side?

Comment: It can stay, it won't harm the app's execution, and can give you helpful debugging information. However, it's commonly not included in Release builds, because it can also expose information about your app and your development environment that you won't want floating around.